# How can I simplify expressions correctly?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, symbolic, built-in-symbols

the final output of my code gives this expression which i call `ttt`:

```
ttt = Sqrt[f[1] f[2]]/(Sqrt[f[1]/f[2]] (gamma^2 + f[1] f[2]));
```

Now i want to simplify this expression for obvious reason. If i do :

```
Simplify[ttt]

FullSimplify[ttt]

Collect[ttt, f[1], f[2]]
```

I obtain:

```
Sqrt[f[1] f[2]]/(Sqrt[f[1]/f[2]] (gamma^2 + f[1] f[2]))

Sqrt[f[1] f[2]]/(Sqrt[f[1]/f[2]] (gamma^2 + f[1] f[2]))

Sqrt[f[1] f[2]]/(Sqrt[f[1]/f[2]] (gamma^2 + f[1] f[2]))
```

Is there a way to have a simplification for this expression ?

Comment: If you know everything is positive, `ttt//PowerExpand` works.  Otherwise, specify some `Assumptions` with simplify.

Comment: @BillWatts yes it works with `ttt // PowerExpand`, in this case i can't use `Assumptions` because the problem is a trivial division.

Comment: @siderius, if it were trivial then Mathematica would have simpified it without assumptions. That is the point. You can use `Assumptions` like this: `Simplify[ttt, f[1] > 0 && f[2] > 0]`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer yes it works this way too. I wonder why it is necessary this assumption if the simpl is mathematically indipendent from this.

Comment: It is required because MMA doesn't know whether the f's are positive, negative, or complex, and therefore, it doesn't know which simplification is correct.

Comment: Try this: `FindInstance[ttt != PowerExpand[ttt], {f[1], f[2], gamma}]`. It gives you a specific case where `ttt` and the "simplified" answer are not the same. Your simplification is simply not always correct. It **is** correct when `f[1] > 0, f[2] > 0` though. That's why you need to specify it, or imply it by using `PowerExpand`.